# Bundling css files as linktag doesn't work

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have css and scss files which in webpack I load with sass-loader and style-loader, like this:

```
test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                url: false,
                modules: false
            }
        },
        { loader: 'sass-loader' }
    ]
```

Everything works except they are all put in  tags which I don't like. I would like to use the 'linkTag' option instead. So, I add that option and the rest of the code is left as it is:

In my view .cshtml file I load the bundled js file which is an output from webpack (this code is the same as previously without the lingTag option and it worked then):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/app/dist/homepagecss.js")
```

And after I open the app now I get that the URL is too big and server error. What is happening is, it opens the code inside and tries to execute it as a server call. I don't understand why this is happening, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using [`extract-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/extract-loader/) and [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/):

```js
{
    test: /style\.css$/i,
    use: [{ loader: "style-loader", options: { injectType: "linkTag"} },
        "file-loader",
        "extract-loader",
        "css-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ],
},
```